# DS18B20 - is current consumption of pullup resistor relevant for battery powered project

Tags: power-supply, sensor, i2c, low-power

In my project, I'll be using a DS18B20 digital temperature sensor, which requires a pullup resistor of around 4.7k between VCC and the signal.

[Please see the datasheet here for reference.](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf)

Is there any current flowing over that pullup when my MCU sleeps and no measurement is performed with the DS18B20.
Basically, I have the same general question for I2C sensors, do those regularly draw current or just during operation?

Comment: You have two questions and they may not have the same answer. The answer to your first question depends on if you use separate 5V supply for 1-Wire sensor or parasitic power via the said resistor.

Comment: Make sure the "signal" wire is floating or high when the DS18B20 is not being accessed. Otherwise, there will be about 1mA of current (in the case of Vcc = 5V) through the resistor or less if you're using a lower supply voltage.

Comment: Well, pull ups drain currents only when there's a corresponding load, so you should see how much your input need for bias. In some ultra low power circuitry you actually turn off the pullup supply for this reason. As for the sensor consumption there's always a baseline plus a dynamic consumption; often there's a standby mode too, it all depends on the part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current exists when there is voltage difference. If you pull a line up to 5V and it sits there, there is no current (ignoring nanoamp or picoamp leakage and stuff). When line goes down in, for example, I2C, then the line is at 0V, but the other side of pullup is still at 5V, so there is current through the pullup. It's important to know the state of the pins when MCU sleeps, which I don't know. If the pins are input during sleep, you can treat it as no current. Which is likely, but you will probably need to measure voltage across pullup resistor when MCU sleeps.

I would expect it to NOT consume any current, but you have to either find or explicitly set pin states in/before sleep mode using datasheet and/or measure voltage across pullup (0V will mean no voltage difference across pullup and thus no current).

Comment: From my understanding the pullup/pulldown are always required to battle the capacitance. To be on the safe side I can also use a GPIO for outputting power to the sensor or for the pullup rail. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, you can use GPIO to power the pullup, but again you don't know what happens when MCU goes to sleep. Most likely, you'll be OK, but you should consult the datasheet to be sure

Comment: @MarcoBobinger "battle capacitance" - capacity only matters when there is actual transmission, so what Ilya wrote does still apply. You might need to consider the power consumption of the sensor and cut it with a transistor if neccessary (don't use a bare gpio). Using a gpio for the pullup reference is quite elegant IMHO, because then you can be sure what the bus does when in sleep mode.

Comment: @SimSon I have previously powered sensors over GPIO, many sensors have power ratings in the mA-range. What disadvantage do you see there? Is the voltage supply not stable or should there be some passive circuitry for filtering?

Comment: @MarcoBobinger using a GPIO for power supply *can* be fine if the sensor requires less current than what the GPIOs are rated for. Digital sensors are no "stable" loads, they will cause peak currents that are above the average consumption (which those mA) refere to. At least if you want to add more sensors, this can become a problem and switching their supply only costs one p-channel MOSFET.

Comment: @SimSon thank you for the comment, I've previously looked into suitable MOSFETs for that, typical N-MOSFETs like the IRF44Z-n have Vth of max 4V, which is not really suitable. The NDP6020 with max 2V Vth could work better, what component do you recommend here? How does the wiring look like, Source connected to GND and sensor rail and Gate to GPIO pin? Isn't it a bad practice to switch GND rail of sensors, shall I better design for switching VDD?

Comment: @MarcoBobinger yes, you should switch Vcc (not GND), because otherwise the signal pin will see a negative voltage when the signal is low while the sensor is powered off. You'd need a Pmos with low Vgs,th. But really, if this is not intended for market and you know the power consumption will be marginal, just do it your way.

Answer (score 1):

This should clarify your doubts. As you know, we will only conduct current when there's a straight path to ground. Therefore, during your off/sleep scenarios you should check what the voltage levels should be.

[image]